# How can I modify a widget parameter field information before saving it?

Tags: magento, plugins, widget, magento2

There is a Widget(ImageSlider) inserted in to a page via the PageBuilder.

One of the widget's parameters is a MultiSelect field (`xsi:type="block"`) and I was ask to either replace it with a `DynamicRowsDragAndDrop` component. After searching for an implementation, apparently I can not implement such a component on a Widget (please point me in the right direction if I am wrong).

Another solution was to change the order of the elements selected on the MultiSelect field before saving the Widget(ImageSlider), by implementing method `beforeSave` via a `Plugin` and `id.xml`.

I believe that I have implemented the solution correctly but when I click on save either at widget or page button nothing happens.

`di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Block\ImageSlider">
        <plugin name="before_save_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Module\Plugin\BeforeSavePlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

`BeforeSavePlugin.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class BeforeSavePlugin extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $log;

    /**
     * @param LoggerInterface $log
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        LoggerInterface $log
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry);
        $this->log = $log;
    }

    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $this->log->debug('Plugin');
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "<script>console.log('hello');</script>";
        var_dump($this->debug());
        echo "</pre>";
        parent::beforeSave();
    }
}
```

Note: echos and var_dumps are there so that I can see if there is a reaction and when it is occurring. But I can't see any messages.
I have run already.
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush

**The objective** is to intercept/load the information submitted through the widget (objet/array?), locate the MultiSelect field, reorder its data and send it on its way.